# object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, наследование, datetime

Интереса ради решил поиграться с классами и заметил такую интересную штуку. Допустим, я хочу создать класс, который будет являться `datetime.datetime` с одним дополнительным атрибутом:

```py
import datetime


class Foo(datetime.datetime):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Вызываем конструктор родителя
        self.foo = 5 # Добавляем свой атрибут
```

При попытке создать экземпляр класса с параметрами:

```py
f = Foo(2020, 1, 1)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6b5ccf5358aa> in <module>
----> 1 f = Foo(2020, 1, 1)

<ipython-input-1-31281291039f> in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      4 class Foo(datetime.datetime):
      5     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
----> 6         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Вызываем конструктор родителя
      7         self.foo = 5 # Добавляем свой атрибут
      8

TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Из-за чего ошибка и как добиться того, что я хочу?

---

Код целиком для копипаста:

```py
import datetime


class Foo(datetime.datetime):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Вызываем конструктор родителя
        self.foo = 5 # Добавляем свой атрибут


f = Foo(2020, 1, 1)
```

Comment: super().__init__() без агрументов не будет правильно ?

Comment: @Интик Действительно. Не очевидно, что родитель подхватывает аргументы конструктора из дочернего класса. Что-то даже не знаю, как правильно загуглить это...

Comment: А вот так `class A :  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   self.lst = args;
class Foo(A):     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  super().__init__()` -  не подхватывает

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В библиотеке `datetime` используется несколько непривычный метод конструирования объекта (который иногда встречается в модулях стандартной библиотеки). А именно, инициализация аттрибутов объекта происходит в методе `__new__`, `__init__` же в свою очередь не переопределяется (определен в `object`), поэтому его вызов не нужен.

В вашем случае явный вызов метода `__init__` родителя по дереву наследования приводит к вызову `object.__init__()`.

Без вызова конструктора родителя:

```
import datetime

class Foo(datetime.datetime):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.foo = 5 # Добавляем свой атрибут


f = Foo(2020, 1, 1)
print(f, f.foo, sep='\n')
# 2020-01-01 00:00:00
# 5
```